# How can i change text orientation in XWPFDocument?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am working right now in producing word documents in java and i am using XWPFDocument of POI Apache. The final document must looks like this

http://sk.uploads.im/t/rtwvm.png

till no everything works fine, I created table, managed to merge cells but i can not find a way to change the text orientation in table cells. I simply want "Type 1" to be upward.
I only found a solution using cellStyle which seems to work only in excel and not in word, which i am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to create two documents in Word, one with the normal orientation and one with the changed one, then unzip them (.docx is actually a Zip-File) and analyze which xml-structure is responsible for this.

Then you can check if POI already offers higher level APIs for these or if you need to access the low-level POI classes via the `getCTxxx()` methods, e.g. `XWPFTableCell.getCTTc()` returns the underlying XML structure and allows you to do things that are not possible via the normal POI interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It simply answered all of my questions, though because of inefficient design in apache-poi libraries the actual coding took a lot of time from me. I will try to post codes asap for other people who may be interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like: `cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewTextDirection().setVal(STTextDirection.BT_LR)`,
 where the parameters are found in: [STTextDirection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/STTextDirection.java#STTextDirection).

The problem I couldn't solve yet is that the row height does not update automatically to the vertical text length, then the text is not completely showed. If you solve it, please, post here.